# What is the recommended way to deploy kafka to make it deploy in all the available nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I have 3 nodes in k8s and i'm running kafka (3 cluster).
While deploying zk/broker/rest-proxy, its not getting deployed in all the available nodes. How can i make sure that all pods are deployed in different nodes. Do i need to use nodeaffinity or podaffinity ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want all pods to run on different nodes - you must use [PodAntiAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity-beta-feature). If this is hard requirement - you must use `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` rule. If it's not - use `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`.

`topologyKey` should be kubernetes.io/hostname.

In `labelSelector` put your pod's labels.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using soft anti-affinity which will look like:

```
affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app
              operator: In
              values:
              - <your app label>
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        weight: 100
```

Here I explained the difference between anti-affinity types with examples applied to a live cluster:
https://blog.verygoodsecurity.com/posts/kubernetes-multi-az-deployments-using-pod-anti-affinity/

Comment: Can i use `nodeSelector:
        label: node1` , will this be a feasible approach ?

Comment: yes but you have to customize selector for every pod then. Using anti-affinity achieves exactly what you need without locking you to particular nodes